# python referencing null array value in function

Tags: python, pandas

I am sending values from a dataframe to a function as per the following, however when the value C2y is null the function returns Nan as opposed to 1, which is what I am trying to do with the last line. I have also tried just 
using (else: 0), which also doesn't work.

Thanks for any help.

```
df['NewColumn'] = list(map(func, df['C1x'],df['C2y']))

def func(x,y):
if x < y:
    return 1
if x >= y:
    return 0
elif pd.isnull(y) is True:
    return 1
```

The result set looks like this

```
  |"C1x"| "C2y" | "NewColumn"
1 |3    | Nan   |  NaN*
2 |4    | 5     |  0
```

*Where I am trying to get the function to return 0 not NaN

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Does it raise an exception (if so you should post the stack frame) or output a result you don't expect (in which case, you should post the output)?

Comment: @zehnpaard - output posted, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you try `type(pd.isnull(df['C2y'][0]))`, you find that it actually returns `<type 'numpy.bool_'>` as opposed to `<type 'bool'>`.  So the identity test `is True` is yielding `False`, which is why you got `NaN` as output of the function.

The simple solution is to not use the `is True` construct.  Try the following:

```
def func(x,y):
    if x < y:
        return 1
    if x >= y:
        return 0
    elif pd.isnull(y):
        return 1 # Actually this should be `return 0` if you want "0 not NaN"
```

Comment: So that works thank you! I don't really get how though. 
How come the pd.isnull(y) is needed at all? Does passing null variables
to functions require special handling (I've only been programming python for about 2 weeks). Thanks again for getting this to work.